# Powershell robo copying sub directory's into one directory

Tags: powershell

Needing help with robo copying sub directory's into one directory.

C:\test\a\suba > c:\root\suba

C:\test\b\subb > c:\root\subb

C:\test\c\subc > c:\root\subc

Answer (score 0):

Why are you asking for "PowerShell robo copying" - are you looking for a PowerShell solution or do you want to use robocopy?

If you're looking for a PowerShell solution, you can do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\test\*\* | ForEach-Object { 
  Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination c:\root\ -Recurse 
}
```